# PHP File is getting Included, but CSS of that File is not

Tags: php

I have a Folder name called Test2. Inside Test2 contains "universal.php" and "universal.css". Also inside Test2, is another folder called article. Inside article, contains a file called template.php. With template.php, I am trying to require_once universal.php. I am using this:

```
<?php
       require_once "../universal.php";
?>
```

This is displaying the PHP, but not the CSS that goes with the file. universal.php is linked to universal.css. Whenever, I make a new file inside of test2, and require_once using just this:

```
<?php
require_once "universal.php";
?>
```

it works. universal.php is displayed with the css properties of universal.css. How do I make it so that template.php gets the css properties of universal.css?

Comment: please show code of css include.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I am not including CSS in template.php. Just universal.php. universal.css is linked to universal.php

Comment: Inline the CSS or adjust the path of the CSS file according to current directory where you are including the file. (Hint: In `universal.php`, set the path for css as `../universal.css` as you are going to access the file from the inner directory).

Comment: try __DIR__ directory... as like require_once __DIR__."\universal.php";

Answer (score 2):

in universal.php try  `../universal.css`
because you are calling `universal.php` inside `template.php` so directory occurs for `template.php`

Comment: universal.css and universal.php are in the same folder, when I require_once in universal.php for ../universal.css the css still doesn't show up in the template

Comment: Whenever I do this, the actual CSS code shows up on the page, the CSS properties don't change the HTML properties of the universal.php

Comment: put them inside a style tag  <style>
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>